# Python Socket With Multiple Clients

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I'm working on a simple chat server project in python as a first experience with sockets, and for some reason I am having hard time letting multiple users to access the server at once (which kinda ruins the concept of chat), or even doesn't allowing a single user to access the server for the second time after it quit. I know something about threading but cannot understand how to use it. Basically this is my server-side code:

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0",PORT))
server_socket.listen(10)
print("Server is up and running")

connected_clients = {}

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
print("Client connected")
while True:
    request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode().split(';')
    if request[1] == 'HANDSHAKE': client_socket.send(f'{time.time()};TRUE'.encode())
    elif request[1] == 'SELECT_USERNAME':
        if request[2] in connected_clients.keys(): client_socket.send(f'{time.time()};FALSE'.encode())
        else: client_socket.send(f'{time.time()};TRUE'.encode()); connected_clients[request[2]] = client_socket
    elif request[1] == 'FIND_RECIPIENT':
        if request[2] in connected_clients.keys(): client_socket.send(f'{time.time()};TRUE'.encode())
        else: client_socket.send(f'{time.time()};FALSE'.encode())
    elif request[1] == 'MESSAGE':
        recipient = connected_clients[request[3]]
        recipient.send(';'.join(request).encode())
    else: print(f'{time.time()};ERROR')
```

Any insights will help!

Comment: Put the `accept()` in a loop. Every time `accept()` returns with a new client connection create a thread to handle the i/o for that connection.

Comment: you have to run `accept()` in loop to get next client in the same time - but it blocks code so it also means you have to run every client in new thread.

Comment: example with comments - [server.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/socket/basic/version-4/server.py)